# VB.Net AddHandler to entire User Control

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

Got a UserControl designed with several Labels and PictureBoxes.
Now I do integrate this UserControl via `Controls.Add` to a Panel where they get displayed the main Form1.

Now I like to raise an event once a UserControll is clicked or hovered.

If I do it via `AddHandler taskItem.MouseClick, AddressOf meClick` but its only triggered when I click the empty space of this Usercontrol and not on a label or PictureBox.

The goal is to use the Event to remove the clicked UserControl from the Label.

EDIT:

This is how my UserControl looks like:

```
Public Class Taks
Private Sub Taks_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each childControl As Control In Controls
        AddHandler childControl.MouseClick, AddressOf Form1.meClick
    Next
End Sub


Public Sub AddTasks(ByVal task_label As TaskLabels, ByVal show_seperator As Boolean, ByVal task_subject As String, ByVal task_message As String)
    taskTitel.Text = task_subject
    taskDesc.Text = task_message

    If task_label = TaskLabels.General Then
        taskImage.Image = My.Resources.Information_50px
    End If
    If task_label = TaskLabels.Important Then
        taskImage.Image = My.Resources.Error_48px
    End If
    If task_label = TaskLabels.Critical Then
        taskImage.Image = My.Resources.Box_Important_50px
    End If

    BunifuImageButton1.Hide()

End Sub

Enum TaskLabels
    General = 0
    Important = 1
    Critical = 2
End Enum
End Class
```

And here I integrate the UserControl into a panel

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddTasks(Taks.TaskLabels.Critical, False, "Batterie Spannung", "low power")
    AddTasks(Taks.TaskLabels.Important, False, "Wetter", "Das Wetter hat sich verschlechtert, Wind > 15km/h")
    AddTasks(Taks.TaskLabels.General, False, "Server", "Auslastung liegt bei 12%")
    AddTasks(Taks.TaskLabels.Important, False, "Temperature", "Temperatur der Proben im Kritischen Bereich")

End Sub


Sub AddTasks(ByVal taksLabels As Taks.TaskLabels, ByVal task_sep As Boolean, ByVal taskTitle As String, ByVal TaskDesc As String, Optional ByVal toFront As Boolean = False)

    Dim taskItem As New Taks
    taskItem.AddTasks(taksLabels, task_sep, taskTitle, TaskDesc)

    taskItem.Dock = DockStyle.Top
    AddHandler taskItem.MouseClick, AddressOf meClick

    taskItem.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    Panel1.Controls.Add(taskItem)
End Sub

Public Sub meClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)

    If MessageBox.Show("delete Event?", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        Panel1.Controls.Remove(sender)
    End If
    BunifuVScrollBar1.Maximum = Panel1.Height
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how events work.  It's just like how a form doesn't raise a `Click` event when you click a `Button` on it.  If you want the UC to raise a `MouseClick` event when a child control is clicked on then you need to handle the event of the child control internally and then raise the UC's event yourself.  E.g.

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each childControl As Control In Controls
            'Filter specific control types if desired.
            If TypeOf childControl Is Label OrElse TypeOf childControl Is Panel Then
                AddHandler childControl.MouseClick, AddressOf ChildControls_MouseClick
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChildControls_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dim childControl = DirectCast(sender, Control)

        'Translate location on child control to location on user control.
        Dim translatedLocation = PointToClient(childControl.PointToScreen(e.Location))

        Dim args As New MouseEventArgs(e.Button,
                                       e.Clicks,
                                       translatedLocation.X,
                                       translatedLocation.Y,
                                       e.Delta)

        'Raise the event of the user control.
        OnMouseClick(args)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: great thx!
Now to remove the Control I clicked I need to distinguish between sender and childControl How is this done the best way.
`Panel1.Controls.Remove(childControl.Parent)`
or
`Panel1.Controls.Remove(sender)`

Comment: Because it's the UC raising its own event, when the form handles that event, the `sender` parameter of the event handler will be the UC, whether it was actually the UC or one of its children that was clicked.  That means that you can use the latter line you just posted in all cases.

Comment: this those not work see my code above. Do I miss something?

Comment: It's like you didn't read what I posted at all.  The UC handles the events for all its child controls and then raises its own event.  You've just got the form handling the event directly for the child controls.  Do what I said and what I showed and it will work.

Comment: oh man sorry for that I didn't get that the `OnMouseClick(args)` will raise the event on the Form side... Of course it does work! great